# Why does LD map sections in this manner for ELF64 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nasm, ubuntu-18.04, ld, elf

Using

> GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30

in a makefile

```
App: App.o Init.o SubRtx.o
    ld -oApp SubRtx.o Init.o App.o

App.o: App.asm
    nasm -g -felf64 App.asm -oApp.o

Init.o: Init.asm
    nasm -g -felf64 Init.asm -oInit.o

SubRtx.o: SubRtx.asm
    nasm -g -felf64 SubRtx.asm -oSubRtx.o

clean:
    rm *.o App
```

Segments are mapped in the following manner.

```
[ 1] .text    PROGBITS 4000b0 0000b0 00023f 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 2] .rodata  PROGBITS 4002f0 0002f0 000018 00   A  0   0 16
[ 3] .data    PROGBITS 600310 000310 0000d0 00  WA  0   0 16
```

In my assembler files, sections are simply declared as **section .data** and **section .rodata** and by design *App.o* is the only file with a **.data** section, hence it is why it is mapped @ 0x600310

I might be getting confused with Windows or maybe even ELF32, but I want to seem to remember by default segments started @ even 4K boundaries. IE: .data would be @ 0x600000 or at least 0x601000, but copying the contents of TEXT section to DATA right from 0x400000 and then DATA not starting until 0x310 seems to be an unnecessary waste.

Intentionally, my application is completely self contained (static linkage) and interfaces with OS via *SYSCALL* exclusively. Code works as expected and I've even erased contents from 0x600000 -> 0x60030f without adverse implications, but am still curious why does this happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Segments are mapped in the following manner.

These are sections, not segments (they are not the same thing).

> .data would be @ 0x600000

It is impossible to `mmap` the data segment that starts at offset `0x310` in the executable file to any location in memory that is not equal `0x310` modulo page size.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52547027/50617) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857735/50617) answer.